# Get control of Radio Button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have radio buttons, around 200, whose ID are KP1, KP2, KP3... KP200. I would like to run a for loop to check if they are checked or not.

I get a crash at the line no 9:

```
RbId = CtrlId;
```

I would like to extract the Radio Button Ctrl from the string similar to how it's done using javascript ie.,

```
document.getElementById("<%=ID%>").
```

Please advise.

**Code:**

```
int i;
RadioButton RbId = null;
string CtrlId = null;
char[] KPList = new char[200];

for (i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
{
    CtrlId = "KP"+i.ToString();
    RbId = CtrlId;
    if(RbId.Checked)
    {
        KPList[i] = (char)j;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this wpf? winforms or something like that?

Comment: Its web application.

Comment: Then please include that in the tag. ASP.NET I guess?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`FindControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx) method in for it:

```
Control ctrl = this.FindControl(CtrlId);

if (ctl is RadioButton)
{
    RadioButton rdBtn = ctrl as RadioButton;
    // now do whatever here
    if(rdBtn.Checked)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: FindControl(CtrlId) returns NULL. Maybe since I call this from Button click, "this" returns NULL. I need to check the entire web page application for the controls. Any suggestions to check for the entire document for controls.! Thanks.

Comment: Your solution to use FindControl helped a lot. The radio buttons are in different panels. Presently, PanelId.FindControl returns TRUE. But would like to write it for the entire radio buttons in the web application. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @Jones ``this`` refers to current page i guess,may be your controls are inside a user control so it may be not able to find them,btw you can do ``Page.FindControl()``

Comment: you are doing it in asp.net webforms?

Comment: Yeah. I am using asp.net webform.!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (RadioButton rdbtn in myDiv.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())//Assume the RadioButtons are inside a div tag called myDiv
{
    if(rdbtn.Checked)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

It would be even better like this:

```
foreach (RadioButton rdbtn in myDiv.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().Where(rdbtn => rdbtn.Checked))
{
}
```